# Lexical error at charcter \US

Tags: haskell, filter

I need to remake this functions with high order functions. I don't know how to change `lookupTitle` but the other I've already changed. But I've got an error on `bookAuthors`.

```
type Title = String
type Author = String
data Product = Book Title Author
                   | Video Author
                   | CD Title Integer Author
                   deriving (Eq,Show)

getTitle (Book title _ ) = title
getTitle (Video title  ) = title
getTitle (CD title _ _ ) = title

getTitles l = map (\x->getTitle x) l
lookupTitle _ [] = Nothing
lookupTitle x (y:ys) | getTitle y == x = Just y
                     | otherwise       = lookupTitle x ys

lookupTitles a b = map (\x->lookupTitle x b) a

 bookAuthors l = filter author l 
                       where author (Book _ _) = True
                                  author _ = False
```

Why?

Comment: You should provide more context. What are you trying to do, what result you expect and what is the error you get?

Comment: Your problem is, as Mikhail Glushenkov points out, with indentation, take a look at the following link for an explanation of how indentation works in Haskell: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an indentation problem. [This](https://gist.github.com/1299937) compiles without errors.

Comment: Yup. Looks like `bookAuthors` is indented one extra space. I highly recommend an editor where you can use a monospace font, especially for a language like Haskell where whitespace matters.

Comment: I use GHC and notepad. HUGS doesn't compile it too. Even without space before bookAuthors.

I've copied code from answer and it starts to work!

Comment: @Артём Царионов: You should try any other text editor the notepad. It is just not meant to be used for programming. See the following link for editors that work well with Haskell on Windows, if you are used to notepad then I suggest you try notepad++: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Windows .